# Vector of const objects giving compile error

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++98

I have declared the following in my code

```
vector <const A> mylist;
```

I get the following compile error -

```
new_allocator.h:75: error: `const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(const _Tp&) const \[with _Tp = const A]' and `_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(_Tp&) const [with _Tp = const A]' cannot be overloaded
```

But if declare -

```
vector <A> mylist;
```

my code compiles.

Is const not allowed in this context?

I am copying my code here for everyone'e reference -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    A () {cout << "default constructor\n";}
    A (int i): m(i) {cout << "non-default constructor\n";}

private:
    int m;
};

int main (void)
{
    vector<const A> mylist;

    mylist.push_back(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? This works fine for me.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with const items?

Comment: @petric - I have compiled it with g++ (GCC) 3.4.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t)

Comment: @underscore_d Compiled with gcc 3.4.3: not c++11.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Items in a vector must be assignable (or, in more recent versions of the standard, movable). `const` objects aren't assignable, so attempting to store them in a vector will fail (or at least *can* fail -- the code is invalid, but a compiler is free to accept it anyway, if it so chooses, though most programmers would generally prefer that invalid code be rejected).

I suppose for the truly pedantic, if you wanted to badly enough, you could define a type that was assignable despite being `const`, something like this:

```
class ugly { 
    mutable int x;
public:
    ugly const &operator=(ugly const &u) const { 
        x = u.x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I believe you *should* be able to store items of this type in a `vector` even though they're `const`. A quick test of creating a vector of these succeeds with VC++. This failed with some older compilers (e.g., failed with g++ 4.8.1), but works with reasonably recent ones (VC++ back to at least 2015, g++ back to at least 5.4 and clang++ back to at least 4.0--though I haven't tried to track down the first version of each that supported it).

For a current compiler, a type that supported moving `const` objects would probably work just as well. But, just in case it wasn't obvious: this is allowing you to modify an object even though it's marked `const`. That's clearly a direct violation of any reasonable user's expectations, so it's mostly a problem, not a solution.

Comment: Actually you can use a vector over non-assignable items. Just you can not use a lot of member functions / algorithms, like push_back.

Comment: @lip: You might be able to get away with it in some cases, but I believe in every case the requirement in the standard is that T be either MoveAssignable or CopyAssignable.

Comment: We just ran into the same problem. The code compiled and works fine in VC++ (2012) but neither g++ 4.8.2 nor clang 3.4 like it.

Comment: The "items in a vector must be assignable" is from C++03; this requirement was relaxed for C++11. (However it is not completely clear whether a vector of `const` objects is permitted on C++11; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c0x-allow-vectorconst-t))

Comment: `const`-ness of a variable means that the variable cannot be changed once assigned. So, I do not understand: why wouldn't one ever want to put into a vector objects that should never be changed once in the vector? I also do not see why push_back should not work.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: What you'd *want* to do isn't the point. The point is the requirements that the standard places on items you put in a vector. I originally answered this based on C++03, which required items to be assignable. As of C++11, that's been relaxed somewhat, so a type that can be moved but not assigned is allowed. Something like a const int, however, is neither moveable nor assignable, so it doesn't qualify. I'm not going to try to debate on a philosophical level whether that's good or bad, but it is what's (currently) required.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Were you asking why someone *would* want a vector of `const` elements? I don't think it's a particularly outlandish scenario. It might be nice in some situations to call a function and say '_give me a bunch of `T`s, but in a way that ensures I can't modify them later, although I reserve the right to add more to the container myself or to destroy them when I'm done_'. That is what a non-`const vector` with a `const value_type` would provide, but due to the allocator requirements, we can't have that. cf also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t

Answer (score 5):

The use of the `push_back` method is the problem. `emplace_back` will compile.
Another alternative (depending on the whole situation you do not describe here) would be to use a `vector<A const&>` if the inserted items have a life outside the vector.
Items in a vector do not need to be assignable, but when they are not, some member functions and algorithms can not be used.

**Explanation :**

`push_back` is supposed to *first* default-construct an A in the vector, *then* assign (using copy-construct) the given reference. This breaks your `const` qualification, hence does not compile.

`emplace_back` uses "perfect forwarding" to invoke the actual constructor directly in place.

Comment: Generally correct, but `emplace_back` does not use the object's move constructor. It uses "perfect forwarding" to invoke the actual constructor directly in-place. See (e.g.) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Comment: I thought containers are not allowed to store references either (or at least not a `vector`.  `vector<A const&>` does not compile

Comment: Containers cannot store references. How on Earth did this get 7 upvotes?

Comment: @underscore_d: Actually, it's gotten 17 upvotes (and 10 downvotes).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I can't recall whether 6 years ago I had the ability to see the separate counts, so either I was talking about the aggregate result, or perhaps others have voted in those 6 years... good to know though :-)

Comment: @underscore_d: Yeah--mostly I found it interesting (bordering on amazing) that years later, the visible score hadn't changed at all.