# Can't Create a const Member of std::pair in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, constants, std-pair

```
std::vector< std::pair< const QTextCharFormat, std::vector< std::tr1::regex > > > foo;
std::vector< std::pair< const QTextCharFormat, std::vector< std::tr1::regex > > > bar;
```

Won't work on gcc 4.6.3 because I cannot call: `bar.push_back( std::make_pair( foo.first, foo.second ) );` This compiles and runs fine on Visual Studio, but under gcc I get:

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:156:2: error: passing ‘const QTextCharFormat’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘QTextCharFormat& QTextCharFormat::operator=(const QTextCharFormat&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Is there an intermediate that Visual Studio is skipping that gets created under gcc?

Comment: It would probably help if you posted a bit more about the definitions of `foo` and `bar` in the example you say doesn't compile. (I presume they aren't the vectors in your first lines!) The error looks a lot like QTextCharFormat::operator= is being passed an rvalue which can't be converted into a const reference. But it's hard to know more without the rest of the question...

Comment: Arg, no they are `std::vectors`, I just messed up on my call. That's fixed now. (Incidentally this works if they are not `std::vectors` somehow trying to push them into the `std::vector` creates the problem.)

Comment: I think it is simplest to just omit the `const` here. The objects in a vector must be assignable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313062/vector-of-const-objects-giving-compile-error):

*Items in a vector must be assignable. const objects aren't assignable, so attempting to store them in a vector will fail (or at least can fail -- the code is invalid, but a compiler is free to accept it anyway, if it so chooses, though most programmers would generally prefer that invalid code be rejected).*

Comment: So it sounds like the problem is that `std::pair< const X, Y >` is not assignable under gcc, but is assignable under Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `bar` is an `std::vector<std::pair<...>>`, therefore trying to assign an `std::pair` (from `std::make_pair`) to it is going to fail. What you probably want is to push back that new `std::pair` into `bar`.

`foo` is also an `std::vector`, therefore you need to select an element and *only then* call `.first` or `.second`:

```
bar.emplace_back(foo[i].first, foo[i].second);
```

But from the way you are using it you most likely mistakenly added an `std::vector` too much in the definitions of both `bar` and `foo`.