# How to std::copy from std::string to std::vector<const int8_t>?

Tags: c++

```
    auto s = fxMessageResponse.SerializeAsString(); //this returns std::string
    std::vector<const int8_t> bytes(s.size());
    std::copy( s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(bytes));
```

This is giving the famous lots of errors like

```
  /home/lz/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1699:31: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void *' with an lvalue of type 'const signed char *'
                  _VSTD::memcpy(__end2, __begin1, _Np * sizeof(_Tp));
```

As far as I know, `int8_t` and `char` are the same for Armv8a. Why do I get this error?

Comment: You can't have a `std::vector` of `const` objects, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313062/vector-of-const-objects-giving-compile-error.  But without that it seems to compile fine, as in https://godbolt.org/z/4KWKhT

Comment: Besides the problem explained in the linked question, you also have another bug. You construct a vector that already has `s.size()` values in it, and then proceed to add ***more*** stuff to it. That's clearly not your intent here. You must fix both issues to make this work.

Comment: *As far as I know, int8_t and char are the same for Armv8a* -- There is no need to guess.  That test can be done at compile-time:  `static_assert(sizeof(int8_t) == sizeof(char), "Sorry, types are not equal size");`

Comment: A `char` is often a `signed char`. It sometimes (very rarely) isn't. I suggest `std::vector<char>`. Why make them `const`?