# Using accessors on reference to vector for iteration in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to iterate over a reference to a vector of strings inside a function. The code originally iterated over an internal copy of the vector but I would like to iterate over the original if possible. However, when I try to do so, I get type mismatch problems.

I tried to work with just portions of an iterator by setting and printing it, but I get similar type mismatching for both the initialization and printing with a %s format specifier. Inside gdb, printing the begin accessor works the same for the reference to the vector or a copy of that to its own vector.

Outside:

```
std::vector<std::string> foo;
foo.pushback('alpha');
foo.pushback('bravo');
func(foo);
```

Inside with copying:

```
void func(const std::vector<std::string> &bar){

    std::vector<std::string> barcopy = bar;

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator barIt = barcopy.begin(); barIt != barcopy.end(); barIt++){
        //operations with the string inside barcopy
    }
}
```

Inside without copying:

```
void func(const std::vector<std::string> &bar){
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator barIt = bar.begin(); barIt != bar.end(); barIt++){
        //operations with the string inside bar
    }
}
```

I expected the reference to behave the same as the copy, but attempting this directly gets me the following when attempting to compile.

```
error: conversion from 
'__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >' 
to non-scalar type 
'__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >' 
requested
```

What type does the begin accessor return when performed on a reference to a vector? How do I go about iterating over this reference without copying?

Comment: See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924328/does-const-containers-have-only-const-iterator).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are passing `bar` as a `const` ref, you need to change:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator barIt = bar.begin(); barIt != bar.end(); barIt++)
```

to:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator barIt = bar.cbegin(); barIt != bar.cend(); barIt++)
```

or, better still, use a ranged for loop, if all you want is to iterate through the elements in the vector:

```
for (auto &elem : bar)
```

Alternatively, change your function signature to `void func(std::vector<std::string> &bar)` (without the `const`).  The ranged for loop will work in either case.

Comment: `cbegin()`/`cend()` returns `const_iterator` not `const iterator`.

Comment: Why do you consider the ranged for loop better? Is it for flexibility? Would this take slightly longer to run than directly defining the iterator type?

Comment: I like its succintness and readability.  Run time should be the same, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Thanks for the material, it looks like that is a good route for me

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you are taking the parameter as a `const` reference. The error is due to trying to take a non-const iterator from a const container. You could fix the error by changing your code to: (take note of the iterator type)

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator barIt = bar.begin(); barIt != bar.end(); barIt++){
    //operations with the string inside bar
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `auto` keyword which will deduce the correct iterator type:

```
for (auto barIt = bar.begin(); barIt != bar.end(); barIt++){
    //operations with the string inside bar
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that need `cbegin` / `cend`?

Comment: @PaulSanders No, `const` versions of `begin()` and `end()` return `const_iterator`.

Comment: @PaulSanders You could use `cbegin`/`cend` make your intention more explicit but `begin`/`end` on a `const` object also return a `const_iterator`.