# How is it that we're allowed to create a const std::vector without any initializer unlike normal const objects

Tags: c++, vector, stl, language-lawyer

I am learning about `std::vector` in C++. I [learnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065617/const-vector-implies-const-elements) that a `const std::vector<int>` means that we cannot change the individual elements within that vector and also cannot append/push_back more elements into it i.e., we only have read-access to the elements, which is expected from an entity that is a `const`. But i find a difference when defining a `const std::vector` than defining other `const` types like `int`, `double` etc. The situation is shown below:

```
int main()
{
    const int i;   //doesn't compiler as expected: initializer needed here 
    const std::vector<int> vec1 ;  //COMPILES FINE: WHY ISN'T AN INITIALIZER NEEDED HERE?

}
```

As we can see that for a `const` built in type(like `int`), we must provide an initializer.

**My first question is** that why isn't this the case for `std::vector`. That is, how(why) are we allowed to omit the initializer for a `const vector`. I mean the `const vector` means that we won't be able to add elements into it so it seems that this `vec1` is useless(practically) now.

So **my second question is** that is there a use for `vec1` ? I mean since the standard allows this so they may have already thought about this case and found out that this `vec1` can be useful somewhere. That is, what are the use cases for this `vec1` that had no initializer at the time of its definition.

Comment: The formal rule is https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-8   My paraphrase is *A const object can't be uninitialized, which means you can't reach the ["no initialization is performed"](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-7.3) outcome when following the rules for default initialization.*

Comment: vec1 isn't allowed by the standard because it, specifically, is "useful". It is allowed because: (1) default constructors exist and (2) const exists. And, yes, both default constructors and const qualifiers are tremendously useful.

Comment: You assume that standard went out of its way to allow empty vectors. That isn't true. The answer explains what happens - object must be initialized. Class objects can't go uninitialized, so they can always be declared `const` without explicit initializer. There was no discussion if they should allow or disallow empty vectors, it was just about `const` primitive types - those can't have *any* use at all if not explicitly initialized (or if they are not global). One use for empty `const` vector would be naming it - so that you could say e.g. `return EMPTY;` instead of `return std::vector<int>{}`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I assumed because i didn't know. To confirm my assumption i asked a question so that experts can tell me if and where/why exactly my assumption is wrong and i can learn from that. That is the whole point of asking a question. An assumption is not the same as a claim. Anyways, thanks for mentioning the use case of `return EMPTY;`.

Comment: @Anya: While that's a valid point, one should never assume that the fact that something happens means that someone specifically *intended* for it to happen or be materially useful. This is especially true of programming and other rules-based domains where emergent properties can occur due to rules interactions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> As we can see that for a `const` built in type(like `int`), we must provide an initializer.

That is incorrect. You must ensure that a `const` object is *initialized*.

If you [do not provide an initializer for an object](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#12), that object will undergo [the process of default initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#7):

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one for the initializer () is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]). The constructor thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.
> - If T is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
> - Otherwise, no initialization is performed.

`vector<int>` is a class type, so the first option is used. The default constructor will be called to initialize it.

`int` is not a class type. It is also not an array type. Therefore, no initialization is performed. And if this happens to a `const` object, the code is ill-formed.

For initializing `const` object, further rules exist:

> If a program calls for the default-initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a const-default-constructible class type or array thereof.

`int` is not a class type or array of class types at all. So any attempt to create a `const`-qualified object of type `int` with default-initialization violates this rule and is ill-formed.

`vector<int>` happens to [follow the rules of `const`-default-constructible](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#7.sentence-2), which is why your code works.

As to whether this particular object is "useful", that's up to you. It's an empty `vector<int>` which cannot be made non-empty. If that's useful to you in some circumstance, then it is useful.

Comment: This is the right rationale, but misses the actual rule.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Are you talking about "const-default-constructible"? Because that doesn't really apply here. It's not what causes the `int` version to error out.

Comment: Certainly it is.  "If a program calls for the *default-initialization* of an object of a `const`-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a *const-default-constructible* class type or array thereof."   When `T` is `int`, it is not a const-default-constructible class type (it is not any class type at all) and also is not an array of one.  Therefore it is not allowed.

Comment: Your answer currently claims "You must ensure that a const object is initialized" without a Standard citation, that's where you should be citing this rule.