# Why can't I push_back to a vector of const elements?

Tags: c++, vector, constants

`push_back`ing to a vector of non-const elements works as expected:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
int bar = 0;
foo.push_back(bar);
```

But why is the following not possible?

```
std::vector<const int> foo;
const int bar = 0;
foo.push_back(bar);
```

More precisely, why is creating the `foo` object possible but not calling `push_back` on it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c0x-allow-vectorconst-t) (with commentary from one of the C++11 designers), `std::vector<const T>` is not permitted by the Standard.

The answer suggests that it might be possible to supply a custom allocator which permits a vector with that allocator to hold const objects.

You're probably better off not attempting to do this.