# vector of const pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants

The following doesn't compile (very verbose error, but basically "cannot be overloaded" and "invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*'").  I can understand why for example push_back() may not compile, as you can't copy/move into a `Foo* const`, but why doesn't this compile:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Foo;

int main()
{
  vector<Foo* const> vec;
}
```

Comment: Full error can be found [here](http://ideone.com/EouxNT)

Comment: In C++03 vector element had to be CopyAssignable. In C++11 it is still not allowed, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t).  In fact I'd suggest closing as duplicate of that question if everyone agrees.

Comment: How do you think you could insert new elements in the `vector` ?

Comment: I was hoping there existed a solution using casts.  Didn't know the language forbid it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The vector is probably the only container that requires the elements to be [copy assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). This is because the elements are guaranteed to be stored contiguously in memory. So if you exceed the capacity, a new chunk has to be allocated and elements re-assigned. You cannot do this with `const` elements.

Same error if you try `std::vector<const int>`, or in fact any `const` type.

Comment: Why does reallocation need assignment? Sounds more like it needs copyability...

Comment: @KerrekSB: From the point of view of the compiler assignment and copyability boil down to the same thing.

Comment: Not any const-qualified type; it should work when the assignment operator is const.

Comment: I actually meant copy-assignable, but I think the idea is the same. edited the answer.

Comment: @райтфолд but how can the `operator=` be ever `const`?

Comment: @vsoftco simple: `T const& operator=(T const&) const { … }`.

Comment: @райтфолд I know how the decl. will look like, but I find hard to understand how you'd implement it without modifying the "guts" of the vector, maybe declaring members as `mutable`....

Comment: Although perhaps `std::vector` simply doesn't work with `const` members regardless: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be481105c08150ca. Should be looked up in the standard to see whether this is an implementation bug.

Comment: @райтфолд I don't think it is, the allocator's typedefs have to match the container's, the container's are what you pass as the type, and the allocator's cannot be `const`.  I think there's an _implicit_ requirement that no container can have `const` elements simply because of the allocator requirements.  I could very well be wrong though.

Answer (score 5):

You are declaring a vector that contain `const` pointer of Foo, that mean that the pointer could not be modified. When you insert an element in the vector would need to write to a `const pointer` (not valid).

You are sure it's not: `std::vector<Foo const *> vec;` where Foo don't be modified by the pointer could.

Comment: I had similar compilation issue like above and indeed the problem was it should be "Foo const *" which means you can modify the pointer value but the not pointed object!

Answer (score 3):

Vector elements need to be assignable for many operations: If you insert an element in the middle of the vector, all the later elements have to be re-assigned. Const-qualified types are usually not assignable.

If you don't perform operations that require assignment, you can still use vectors of non-assignable types, though.

However, you may only use `std::allocator<T>` when `T` is a non-const object type, so `std::vector<const int>` is ill-formed.

Comment: Since C++11 vector elements do not need to be assignable

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Absolutely right, edited.

Comment: @MattMcNabb hmmmm, g++4.9.2 and even gcc5 believes otherwise, but yes, you are correct

Comment: @KerrekSB OK; however according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t) the vector is still not permitted

Comment: In your last sentence, "If you don't perform operations that require assignment, you can still use vectors of non-assignable types, though", doesn't that apply here?  I'm not assigning anything to `vec`.

Comment: @AgrimPathak: Sorry, I was on the wrong track. See update.

Answer (score 1):

The C/C++ `const` keyword is left-associative, i.e. it effects the token to its left, except if `const` is the first token in a statement. So `void *const` means "constant (=immutable) pointer to void".

Hence the semantics are:

```
int a;
void * const ptr = (void*)&a; /* legal */

int b;
ptr = (void*)&b; /* not permitted */
```

the later is illegal because const variables must be initialized at definition and can not be altered later on.

When writing `std::vector<void * const>` you're asking the compiler to instance the template as a vector of immutable pointers to void. However immutable means, it can be assigned to only at definition, which however does not fly with the dynamic nature of `std::vector`.