# Compiler error with std::reference_wrapper and types in C++

Tags: c++, types, stl, reference, constants

I've been diving into C++ lately, and I've been giving STL a go. I'm encountering a problem that I cannot seem to solve. I'm guessing it involves me not understanding how C++ deduces types, but I'm not sure. Here is the code that works

```
template <typename T>
auto most_frequent_element(const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>> &vector) -> boost::optional<std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<T>, size_t>> {
    if (vector.empty()) {
        return{};
    }
    std::map<std::reference_wrapper<T>, size_t> individual_counts = {};
    std::for_each(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [&individual_counts](auto &element) {
        auto result = individual_counts.emplace(element, 0);
        (*result.first).second++;
     });
    return *std::max_element(individual_counts.begin(), individual_counts.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) {
        return a.second < b.second;
    });
}
```

And this is how I might call it

```
auto main(int argc, char *argv[]) -> int {
    std::vector<char> test = { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'};
    auto result = most_frequent_element(std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<char>>(test.begin(), test.end()));
    if (result) {
        std::cout << (*result).first << " " << (*result).second << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Empty input list." << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So that works. But if I create a simple method to eliminate the need to copy the vector manualy, like so

```
template <typename T>
auto most_frequent_element_2(const std::vector<T> &vector) -> boost::optional<std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<T>, size_t>> {
    most_frequent_element(std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>(vector.begin(), vector.end()));
}
```

and call it like this

```
auto main(int argc, char *argv[]) -> int {
    std::vector<char> test = { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'};
    auto result = most_frequent_element_2(test);
    if (result) {
        std::cout << (*result).first << " " << (*result).second << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Empty input list." << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the following error

```
Error C2664 'std::reference_wrapper<char>::reference_wrapper(std::reference_wrapper<char> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char' to 'char &'
```

I'm confused because how I see it they should do the same thing. If I am wrong can someone point me in the right direction.

P.S. I'm working in Visual Studio 2015

**Update:** Added const constraint to return type of functions to correctly reflect the fact that the *max_element returns a const key. (suggested by @dyp)

Comment: As far as I can see, this is a constness issue: the `most_frequent_element_2` functions has a const reference to a vector, so the elements are const when iterating (`const_iterator`s). However, the `reference_wrapper<T>` is a `reference_wrapper<char>`, so it requires non-const elements for its initialization.

Comment: Additionally, there's a constness issue with the return types, which might be due to `boost::optional` being slightly restrictive with its implicit constructors. That is, clang++ rejects your original code because the `*std::max_element` yields a `pair<const reference_wrapper<T>, size_t>` since the key of a map node is const.

Comment: This is why I feel confused. When i try to add const-ness I stumble upon the fact that the C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements.

Comment: So, one solution is to remove the const constraint on the second function. Is there a way make that constraint possible?

Comment: I don't quite see why containers of `const` elements should be illegal. Would you mind citing the passage that forbids this?

Comment: @hitripekac "_the C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements_" That's wrong. The *specific case* of `std::vector` does forbid that, via its allocator requirements, but what you said is not a generality at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t

Comment: @underscore_d you are absolutely correct, it is 100% wrong. I should have deleted the comment, but then the subsequent comments from dyp wouldn't make sense. Anyhow, I now know not spout nonsense without referencing the relevant documents :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues are related to constness. Originally, there's been an issue with the implicit conversion from

```
optional<pair<const reference_wrapper<T>, size_t>> // A
```

to

```
optional<pair<reference_wrapper<T>, size_t>> // B
```

The first one is `const` because the key of `std::map` nodes is `const` - preventing mutation of the key shall ensure that the tree data structure remains valid.

This implicit conversion is not allowed; this might have to do with the issue described for `std::pair` in [Improving `pair` and `tuple` - N4387](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html).

A quick fix is to use `A` as the return type, instead of `B`. Alternatively, use explicit conversion (a cast or construction of a named object).

---

The second issue related to constness is that a

```
reference_wrapper<T>
```

cannot be initialized with a

```
T const&
```

Just like a `T&` cannot be initialized from an lvalue-expression of type `T const`. This issue occurs because the `most_frequent_element_2` function takes its argument by `const&`, then the calls to `begin` and `end` produce `const_iterator`s.

A quick and dirty solution is to create a `vector<reference_wrapper<T const>>` instead:

```
most_frequent_element(std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T const>>(vector.begin(), vector.end()));
//                                                         ^^^^^
```

And then adjust the return type of the `_2` function to

```
boost::optional<std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<T const>, size_t>>
//                                                       ^^^^^
```

[Live demonstration](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uVB6hbe01kaLxQnI)

A better solution might be to recognize that the `_2` function does not need a `vector`, but only two iterators to create a new vector. (The same argument holds for the original `most_frequent_element` function.) You could write it instead as:

```
template <typename InIt,
          typename T = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<InIt&>())>>
auto most_frequent_element_2(InIt b, InIt e)
  -> boost::optional<std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<T>, size_t>> {
    return most_frequent_element(std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>(b, e));
}
```

where I've used the second (defaulted) template parameter merely for convenience (a `typedef` within the declaration).

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DfpNzmTHQxsHs9mE)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The change to iterator is definitely better as it provides a more general solution.