# Compiler error reported for const vector<const T> in VS 2015 but not VS 2013

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, vector, constants, visual-studio-2015

The following code compiles OK using Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string constString("fred");
    const std::vector<const std::string> myVector{ constString };
}
```

If I try to compile it using Visual Studio 2015 the following error is reported:

`1>xmemory0(587): error C2338: The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator<const T> is ill-formed.`

I've seen various posts, and in particular this one [Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6954906/820657), about `vector<const T>` and why it's not allowed but I don't really get it. However, in the above example the vector itself is const.

Can someone please explain? Is VS 2013 wrong to compile it successfully?

Comment: If you don't believe the answer that you linked and especially the comments what would it take to convince you? Howard Hinnant was on the C++11 committee.

Comment: Not a helpful comment. Nowhere does it say I don't believe the answer given, and I did say I don't really get it. Furthermore, myVector is const, which isn't discussed and VS2013 compiles the code.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the vector is const - it still needs to allocate memory in its constructor, for the sole element you want to put into it - and, as the error message suggests, the problem is precisely with the allocator. Clearly it's a diagnostic added in VS2015 that VS2013 lacked, so yes, VS2013 is wrong to compile it successfully.

Comment: It also compiles using Xcode 6.2 - hence my confusion.

Comment: When a vector grows beyond capacity, it allocates a new array and copies all elements to the new array. This requires the elements to be [copy assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable). A const type is by definition not copy assignable (not assignable at all).

Comment: @rustyx: ever heard of a copy constructor?

Comment: Doesn't this have something to do with std::strings actually getting typed to std::basic_string, so it's vector<const std::basic_string> that is actually ill formed? I want to say I remember this being problematic with templating and std::string, just can't remember the details.

Answer (score 2):

```
Standard   Requirement for T
========   =================
C++03      any type
C++11      any non-const, non-reference object type
C++14      any non-const object type
C++17      any cv-unqualified object type
```

Nowhere in the standard does it make an exception for
when the container itself is `const`

So yes, VS 2013 is wrong to compile it successfully.