# Why I can't use a reference type inside a `std::initializer_list`

Tags: c++, oop, stl, initializer-list

when I try to use an initializer list for a member that contains references, I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<const Exp&>::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

I have read several related posts, but first, they seem to get a different error; second, they qualify the use of references "as pointless".

Without getting into philosophical discussions, indeed I would appreciate knowing if it is possible to make the below example work:

```
#include <vector>

class Exp {
};

class Integer : public Exp {
public:
  const int value;
  Integer(const int val) : value(val) { }
};

int main() {

  const auto a1 = Integer(1);
  const auto a2 = Integer(2);

  const std::vector<const Exp&> va{a1,a2};
 }
```

Could it be a missing constructor for the `vector` class? Thanks a lot!

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413
```

[Edited to remove spurious example]

Comment: The problem isn't the initializer list. The problem is that you cannot have a vector of references.

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot! Will read more. What are you supposed to use as a reference container?

Comment: In fact it seems you cannot also put a const inside a container, uh, I'm a total newbie in C++ after 15 years without touching it !

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t
If you want references inside a container, use `std::reference_wrapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everybody!!! I've settled on this solution for now:

```
std::array<const std::reference_wrapper<const Exp>, 2> ae{a1,a2};
```

I need to investigate more but I think that will do what I want for now.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is not explicitly stated in the standard, attempting to use standard library containers to store non-object types should be regarded as undefined behaviour. See [container.requirements.general],

p1: "Containers are objects that store other objects..."

p4: "... `X` denotes a container class containing objects of type `T`..."

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for reference!

Comment: However, the standard library has std::reference_wrapper which is designed specifically to store references in STL or other containers.

Comment: @Nullrelation: `reference_wrapper` isn't quite *designed* for this purpose (it's designed to allow bind expressions to capture references), but they can be used for this.