# Why std::pair<const int, int> does not work with some STL containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

It seems that some containers accept `std::pair<const int, int>` as a value type, but some do not. The problem is of course in the `const` part.

I did some googling and found that only `std::vector` requires copy-assignable data. However, `std::pair<const int, int>` works just fine with `std::vector`, `std::set` and `std::list` (and perhaps other containers), but not with `std::map` and `std::priority_queue` (the latter really bugs me).

The following compiles without problems (gcc 6.1.0)

```
std::vector<std::pair<const int, int>> vector;
vector.push_back(std::make_pair(3, 5));
std::set<std::pair<const int, int>> set;
set.insert(std::make_pair(3, 5));
std::list<std::pair<const int, int>> list;
list.push_back(std::make_pair(3, 5));
```

But this results in compilation errors:

```
std::priority_queue<std::pair<const int, int>> pq;
pq.push(std::make_pair(3, 5));
std::map<int, std::pair<const int, int>> map;
map[2] = std::make_pair(3, 5);
```

> ```
> error: assignment of read-only member ‘std::pair<const int, int>::first’
> ```

What is the reason behind this? Shouldn't `std::map` and `std::set` have the same behavior given that they have the same underlying implementation? Why does it work with `std::vector` although it requires to move data?

Comment: The containers were not designed to contain `const` elements. [See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t)

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. You're attempting an assignment and are complaining that you are not able to assign to constants.

Comment: @S.K.: `vector[0] = std::make_pair(3, 5);` won't work either.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am not complaining, I just want to understand why different containers behave differently and whether this is an expected behavior or not.

Comment: The containers were written for non-const contents and the behaviour you get is mostly coincidental based on what the library writers did to implement the non-const variants

Comment: That has nothing to do with containers. You're simply attempting to assign to a constant.

Comment: _"Shouldn't std::map and std::set have the same behavior ..."_: to test this you need to make the pair<> the key of the map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything that requires assignment will break.

- `vector::push_back` doesn't require assignment, only copy/move construction.
- ditto for `set::insert`.
- ditto for `list::push_back`.
- `priority_queue::push` needs to move around the existing elements to maintain the heap property (via `std::push_heap`), which requires assignment.
- `map[2] = stuff;` is literally an assignment. Use `map::insert` or `map::emplace` if you want it to work.

Comment: `vector::push_back` actually requires to move elements around.

Comment: @Slava It's copy/move construction on reallocation, not assignment.

Comment: @Slava It does. Where did I say it doesn't?

Comment: Then I do not understand why for `std::vector` to move elements it does not require assignments, but for `std::push_heap` it does.

Comment: @Slava `vector` is moving everything to a new location. `push_heap` reorders elements within the sequence, for which assignment is more efficient.

Comment: Erasing elements from a vector or deque also requires assignment.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think for a deque, `pop_front` and `pop_back` do not require assignment.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the answer. I really think that container should not copy the data inside using the assignment operator because this is not a behavior intended by the user and therefore should not limit the use of the container. One solution is to use in-place copy-constructors. For example this is a simple container that does this and can be used with non-copy-assignable types:
`template<typename Data> class MyContainer {
 Data data[10];
 int cpt = 0;
public:
 void set(int i, Data const & d) {
  new (&data[i]) Data(d);
 }

 Data const & get(int i) const {
  return data[i];
 }
};`

Comment: @S.K. You have to destroy first or you just leaked whatever `Data` owned. Regardless, destroy + reconstruct can be considerably more expensive than assignment. The designers sensibly decided not to pessimize everyone else's code for some pathological corner cases.

Comment: @T.C. You are right about the need for destruction. I understand the performance issue, but I still think that, for example, being unable to use std::priority_queue on non-copy-assignable data because it internally tries to copy the data (something that does not concern me as a user and does not fall under my control) is either bad implementation or a design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Let's look at your error more deeply:

> **error: assignment of read-only member ‘std::pair::first’**

### Solution

There is no solution to this! As you can see here, there is a member that is only in read mode.

```
 std::priority_queue<std::pair<const int, int>> pq;
```

Here you can see `const int`. Well, the `const` modifier makes it so that the variable can be only in read mode and **can't** be changed! That's your problem here. If you try to assign a constant, well this results in an error because your attempting to change a constant while it is in **only** READ mode.

### References

[**cpprefrence**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)