# std::initializer_list<int const> cannot be constructed from std::initializer_list<int>

Tags: c++, initializer-list, c++17

My question is about the lack of conversions between `std::initializer_list` types where the contained type is more or less cv qualified when those conversions appear to be easily doable.

Consider the following code which is invalid:

```
std::initializer_list<int> x{1,2,3,4,5,6};
std::initializer_list<int const> y = x; // error! cannot convert!
```

Now consider `std::optional` and ignore the ridiculous types:

```
std::optional<std::vector<int>> x{std::in_place, {1,2,3,4,5}}; // OK
std::optional<std::vector<int const>> y{std::in_place, {1,2,3,4,5}}; // error!
```

I *assume* the language spec requires deducing non cv qualified `U`'s for `std::initializer_list<U>` by default.

As far as I can tell, the whole point of `std::optional` (and `std::any` and `std::variant`) having `std::initializer_list` constructor overloads is to avoid specifying the exact type of the initializer list. To get the second line of the above code to compile, that's exactly what you must do.

`std::initializer_list` already holds a `const*` to it's data (in `libc++` anyhow). There's no reason I can see for the above code not to work? Is this a solvable issue in the language, or am I missing something?

Comment: It's kind of hard to "ignore the ridiculous types", when `vector<int const>` is explicitly *not legal* in C++. So why exactly would you expect `initializer_list<T const>` to work? What would you be initializing with it?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I was writing a generic wrapper type when I discovered this.

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense for some type similar to `dynarray`.

Comment: @NicolBolas based on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t) I would say that `vector<int const>` is *accidentally* not legal, and it might become legal in C++17, not through intent but as a by-product of other changes

Comment: @M.M It's hardly accidental when the allocator requirements table bans it outright.

Comment: @T.C. I mean, when designing the allocator requirements was it part of the rationale that `vector<const T>` not be allowed? The discussion on that thread suggests not.

Comment: Though interesting, the thrust of my question had little to do with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your question is why `std::initializer_list<T const>` cannot be constructed from `std::initializer_list<T>` despite the fact that it would be easy to implement such a conversion.

I think the answer is that you are not supposed to have `std::initializer_list<T const>` in the first place, given that, as you noted, `std::initializer_list<T>` only gives `const` access to its elements anyway.

It might therefore be said that there is a "cultural norm" in C++ that you are not supposed to have any constructors that require a `std::initializer_list<T const>` argument. None of the standard library containers do, for instance, since a cv-qualified value type is illegal anyway (except in the case of `std::array`, which, of course, has no user-defined constructors anyway).

If you write your own type `MyContainer` that supports `MyContainer<T const>`, then I suggest that you make it look like the following:

```
template <class T>
class MyContainer {
  public:
    MyContainer(std::initializer_list<std::remove_cv_t<T>> il);
    // ...
};
```

Comment: "Cultural norm" seems correct! I'll leave this open in case someone (you?) can explain why all initializer lists aren't deduced to be `std::initializer_list<const T>` if they have the same semantics as a `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Comment: @xcvr because the template argument of `std::initializer_list` is deduced using the usual rules of template argument deduction, which will never deduce a cv-qualified type, a reference type, an array type, or a function type.

Comment: Though I think the usual rules of template argument deduction are out the window when the type cannot be deduced unless it is specified as `std::initializer_list<cv U>`.