# Convert std::vector<std::pair<const K, V>*> to std::vector<std::pair<const K, V>>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I want to convert `std::vector<std::pair<const K, V>*>` to `std::vector<std::pair<const K, V>>`. However, as you know due to `pair<const K, V>` I can't assign.

I guess there can be someway to leverage

```
template< class InputIt >
void assign( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

to make this happen. However, I can't find a way out.

Look for advice. Thanks!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t

Comment: Revised the question. std::vector<std::pair<const K, V>> should be legitimate as I see as my compiler doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` is only an issue if you try to assign elements or call certain functions like [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).  But [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) and [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) will be fine.

One solution:

```
template <typename Elem>
std::vector<Elem> deref_vec_elems( const std::vector<Elem*>& v ) {
    std::vector<Elem> v2;
    for ( Elem* e : v )
        v2.push_back( *e );
    return v2;
}
```