# Understanding const pointers to const value in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, reference, constants

I have two questions.

First of all I have a little problem with the understanding of const pointers to const values. I don't get why `B::insert` works, while `C::insert` results in a compiler error. I mean doesn't the list in `C` exactly equals the parameter of `C::insert`?

My second question is whether `A const * const a`, could also be written as `const A& a`.

```
class A
{
    //Do stuff
};

class B 
{
private:
    list<A const *> l;

public:
    void insert(A const * const a)
    {
        l.push_back(a);
    }
};

class C 
{
private:
    list<A const * const> l;

public:
    void insert(A const * const a)
    {
            l.push_back(a);
    }
};
```

Edit (Compile error):

```
g++ -Wall  -c  -O2 "sonnensystem.cpp" -std=c++11 (im Verzeichnis: C:\Users\Kenan\Desktop\OPR\cppcode\Konzepte\Kapselung\Architektur\sonnensystem01)
In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
             from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:46,
             from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/string:41,
             from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
             from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
             from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:42,
             from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
             from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
             from sonnensystem.cpp:1:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'struct __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<const A* const>':
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:92:11:   required from 'class std::allocator<const A* const>'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:315:9:   required from 'class std::__cxx11::_List_base<const A* const, std::allocator<const A* const> >'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:507:11:   required from 'class std::__cxx11::list<const A* const>'
sonnensystem.cpp:28:27:   required from here
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:93:7: error: 'const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = const A* const; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = const A* const*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = const A* const&]' cannot be overloaded
       address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:89:7: error: with '_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = const A* const; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = const A* const*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = const A* const&]'
       address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
Kompilierung fehlgeschlagen.
```

Comment: Would be useful if you would include the compiler error.  My compiler did not have an error.

Comment: @Eljay See my edit. I also tried this online compiler [link](http://cpp.sh/). Didn't work there either :/

Comment: Also see [Does C++11 allow `vector<const T>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t) for why the compiler complains about `address`.

Answer (score 3):

In your declaration `A const * const`, the first `const` says that the `A *` pointer points to a value that can't be changed (a const pointer).  The second `const` says that the value of that pointer can't be changed, just like a `const int` can't be changed.  Since `list` (and other standard containers) require their members to be assignable, they can't be const values.

For your second question, a `A const * const` and `const A&` are similar, but not interchangeable, as the ways you use them are different.

Comment: Thanks, i got that now but why exactly does it need to be CopyAssignable?

Comment: Short answer: Because the language says it needs to be.  Longer answer:  as containers are copied, created, resized, etc., elements will be moved and copied, so the existing values in the containers need to be updateable (assigned by copying).

Comment: Alright thank you for your help :) Is @SoronelHaetir's comment right, tho? I tried it but don't seem to work ;/ Don't want to get this thread closed before knowing whether his answer is correct or not :D

Comment: @SaliKe No, using `emplace_back` will not let it work.  There's more going on internally than just creating the node.

Answer (score 1):

When using `std::list<T>`, one of the requirements for `T` is that it is [`CopyAssignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable). See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list.

When you use a `const` type as the parameter, that requirement is not met. You will see a similar error, if not the same error, if you use:

```
std::list<const int> a;
a.push_back(10);
```

Anyway,

```
list<A const * const> l;
```

is not usable.

Answer (score 0):

The only real difference between `A const * const` and `A const &` is that it is easier to check that the pointer is invalid (you could cast a nul pointer to `A` and then dereference to get a null `A` reference, it's just easier to go `if(!a)`).

The `C::insert` case is due to the code trying to assign to the internal node value. It would probably work if you used `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`.

Comment: I tried to use emplace_back instead of push_back but that didn't work. I think like the other people around here stated already, the generic argument  needs to be CopyAssignable.