# Why does the C++ standard forbid containers of const elements?

Tags: c++, containers, constants, language-lawyer

What is the rationale behind C++11 forbidding containers of const elements? I am referring to the following error message, which you get if you define, for example, a vector of const elements:

> error C2338: The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator<const T> is ill-formed.

If you read similar questions, the answer usually repeats the error message, but never goes into details or even gives an explanation as to why the `static_assert` was introduced. Defining containers of const elements doesn't seem to be an unreasonable thing to do, so why would C++11 forbid it? Since it used to be allowed in earlier versions, what is the exact reason for this limitation?

Here is sample code which fails to compile in VS2017:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

struct foo {};

typedef std::vector<const foo> foo_vector;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo_vector v;
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding the [possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/), it neither provides background nor a reliable answer.

Comment: Do you understand _"allocator<const T> is ill-formed"_?

Comment: What would you like to achieve with such constructs? That sounds like an xy-problem.

Comment: Well, as I said, you just repeat the error message as an explanation.

Comment: By the way: std::array is an exception from...

Comment: How could you implement `insert()` in a `vector<const int>` without forcing a full reallocaiton of the vector regardless of capacity? You'd have a bunch of these hidden implementation inconsistencies between const and non-const versions.

Comment: [Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39652132)

Comment: vector container is a dynamic array.  So vector is never constant. Compiler doesn't like it. Don't use it.

Comment: @Frank: But that's what I want to find out - does it not make sense or did the STL implementors just screw up.

Comment: Should the const elements be allocated in read-only space or read-write space?

Comment: Can you give us a use case for this? Just to understand better in which circumstances it is needed.

Comment: @Frank: why would a full reallocation needed for an insert? It's just a simple placement new.

Comment: If it so much important to you that the vector will contain only const elements, you can simply implement it..

Comment: @geza You can't replace something that's `const`, you can only create or destroy it, that's kind of the whole point.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, but you can move elements around in-place using only destruction and placement new, same as the vector does when resizing without reallocation (note I do mean "resize", not "insert"... insert mainly uses move assignments)

Comment: @Nguaial `std::vector<const foo> a;` is not the same as `const std::vector<foo> a;`

Comment: @BaummitAugen seems like, for c++17, they finally understood the problem

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed in VS2019.