# pass vector with const contents

Tags: c++, constants

I have a vector that looks like this.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > v;
```

and I want to pass it into a function and make it so it's constant.

first I tried

```
void fun(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > v)
```

but that function allowed me to have the line

```
std::pair<int,int> p = v[i];
```

which I thought should have thrown an error since pair is not of type const. Then I realized that it's only the pointers that are being declared constant in vector so I tried

```
void fun(const std::vector<const std::pair<int,int> > v)
```

but that throws the error about there being no conversion.

I'm sure there's some inner workings that I'm not understanding that makes this illegal but would love some insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you confuse reference and value semantics here. Lets the first function signature you tested:

```
void fun(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > v)
```

This copies the function argument into a new object `v`, which is additionaly `const`-qualified. Such signatures seldomly make sense: either you want to pass it as a `const` reference (to avoid copying) or you want to pass it by non-`const` value, because the function body will mutate the argument, but shall operate on its only copy. Besides, this snippet:

```
std::pair<int,int> p = v[i];
```

compiles just fine with the above function signature, because it *copies*  the vector element at position `i` into a new `pair` object. The latter can be mutated, but this doesn't affect the vector at all.

Let's now consider the second function signature:

```
void fun(const std::vector<const std::pair<int,int> > v)
```

The same as before still applies here, and in addition, `std::vector<const T>` isn't useful, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6954906/9593596) for an explanation.

---

**How to fix it?** If you don't want to copy the argument, but the function doesn't modify the vector, pass it by `const` reference. If the function modifies the vector and these modifications shall be visible at the call side, pass it as non-`const` reference. If the function modifies the vector but that shall happen independently of the call side vector, pass by non-`const` value.

Comment: Another reason it's inappropriate: The declaration `void fun(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > v)` is **the same** as `void fun(std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > v)`, top level cv qualification is ignored.

Comment: @Caleth Sorry I don't get that. Did you forget a `const` in the template type?

Comment: No, I mean "Top-level cv-qualifiers are dropped from the parameter type" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: @Caleth Interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

```
void fun(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > v)
{
   ////
   std::pair<int,int> p = v[i];
}
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

No error will happen here because std::vector has overloaded `operator[]` both for const and non-const instances. In your case it will be resolved to const version and return `const &` to underlying `i` element.
Consider following code:

```
void fun(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > v)
{
   ////
   std::pair<int,int> p = v[i]; //OK
   v[i] = std::pair<int,int>{10,20}; //Compile error, trying to modify const data!
}
```