# Why is vector of const pointer working in c++17

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I saw [this answer: Does C++11 allow `vector<const T>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t) explains how you should **not** use `const T` in a `std::vector`. I tried this with `std::vector<const int> int_vector` and got compiler error, which is expected. But if I create an `std::vector<const CustomType*> custom_type_vector` I can use it with no problem. Does this mean c++ allows const pointer as an element within a `std::vector` but does not allow `const T` in `std::vector`?

minimal reproducible example

```
std::vector<const int> vec_a; // compiler will complain this.
std::vector<const int*> vec_a; // compiler will accept this.
```

The error log for using `std::vector<const int>` is:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:93:7: error: 'const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = const int; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = const int*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = const int&]' cannot be overloaded
       address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:89:7: error: with '_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = const int; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = const int*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = const int&]'
       address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:125:19: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
  ::operator delete(__p);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

My compiler version is **gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)**

Comment: const CustomType* is not a constant pointer. It's a pointer on a constant CustomType

Comment: [mcve] please post one

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Apparently I did not know about this. So this makes the element inside std::vector not a const at all.

Comment: Please do not include the answer in the question.  I have rolled back to revision 5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [m_pOatrix correctly points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003410/why-is-vector-of-const-pointer-working-in-c17#comment104257061_59003410), `std::vector<const CustomType*>` is not a vector of const pointers, but a vector of pointers to const objects, and this is allowed.

If you instead had const pointers, this would be disallowed:

```
std::vector<Foo> f; // allowed
std::vector<const Foo> f; // disallowed
std::vector<const Foo*> f;// allowed
std::vector<Foo* const> f; // disallowed
```

The trick with `const` is that it applies to the thing immediately to the left of it, or if it's at the beginning (like it often is) then it applies to the first thing.

```
const Foo*; // pointer to const Foo, same as Foo const*
Foo* const; // const pointer to Foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, apparently this question is due to me lacking of knowledge about the syntax/usage of const keyword. It is tricky but it all makes sense now.

Comment: It would probably more useful to point out that cv-qualifiers go directly behind the type they apply to, but if they are before everything else, as a matter of convenience they are treated as if they were just after the first part.