# std::list<const SomeClass> can not be defined

Tags: c++, constants, stdlist

I'm trying to define a constant list of constant objects and I can't seem to get it done.
Here is my example that compiles fine:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

class Person { public:
    std::string name;
    Person(const std::string &in_name){name=in_name;}
};

class MyClass { public:
    const std::list</* const */Person> l;
    MyClass(const std::list</* const */Person> &in_l):l(in_l){}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Person dave("dave");
    MyClass c(std::list<const Person>(dave));
    return 0;
}
```

When I remove the comments from `const` in those 2 places,
I get the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:41,
                 from main66.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<const Person>’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/allocator.h:108:11:   required from ‘class std::allocator<const Person>’
main66.cpp:11:53:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:93:7: error: ‘const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = const Person; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = const Person*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = const Person&]’ cannot be overloaded
       address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:89:7: error: with ‘_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = const Person; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = const Person*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = const Person&]’
       address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^~~~~~~
```

**Is there any way to define a std::list of const objects**?

Comment: I don't think you can have such a list. You can have a `const std::list<Person>` or a `std::list<const Person *>` but the list need to be able to modify the person values to be a container of those values.

Comment: OP, please be aware that `MyClass c(std::list<const Person>(dave));` does not do what you think it does. This is a function declaration, not a variable definition. Use `{}` instead of `()` to make it do what you want it to do.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Allocator-aware containers*, such as `std::list`, cannot take `const` value types, because the [*Allocator* requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) specify behavior only for *cv-unqualified* types. This means that the container is not guaranteed to be able to create the element objects through the allocator interface if the value type is `const` or `volatile` qualified.

This is not a problem though, because the container being `const` is enough to guarantee that the elements are not changed. If you access an element of the container through a `const` reference to the container, you will only ever get a `const` reference to the element.

So, just use `const std::list<Person>`, instead of `const std::list<const Person>`.

Technically someone could `const_cast` the `const`ness away from such a reference to be able to modify the elements and that would probably be legal, i.e. not undefined behavior, but that is something that a user can always do, just that it would cause undefined behavior with `const` objects.

See also [Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t) for details.

Comment: But then elements are not `const`, so someone could use `const_cast`, thus most optimizations cannot be applied. Is it really the same thing?

Comment: @Ayxan Yes, probably that would be legal. But a user can always do that. The only difference is whether it will work or be UB, so I don't think that is really a concern.

Comment: If that's the case, then why did the explicit restriction on const value types was removed post-C++11? I wonder if you can use a list of `const Person`, but with a `std::allocator<Person>`.

Comment: *"The only difference is whether it will work or be UB"* If it is UB, then compiler can ignore those cases and apply appropriate optimizations. If it is legal, the compiler cannot do that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vMVwLg `std::list must have the same value_type as its allocator` and `std::list must have a non-const, non-volatile value_type`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think there was any restriction specifically against `const` types? The removable of the *CopyAssignable* requirement is probably more related to e.g. classes with `const` or reference members, but not to top-level `const` qualification. I don't think using a different allocator type will work, because the allocator requirements only require the allocator to work with `T*`, not `const T*`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik More concretely, there is an explicit requirement that the allocator value_type and the container value_type are identical: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer

Comment: @Ayxan I think there isn't really anything to optimize, because the user could also placement-new completely different objects into the storage, even if it was `const`. Doing so is only prohibited for non-dynamic storage duration objects: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-10

Answer (score 2):

std::list must have a non-const, non-volatile value_type.

Answer (score 2):

Error message seems clear enough https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MG3Kxv:

> error: static assertion failed: `std::list` must have a non-const,
>   non-volatile `value_type`