# Why can't a std::vector hold constant objects?

Tags: c++, vector, constants

I am not sure why the following code is not allowed to exist:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<const int> v;
    v.reserve(2);
    v.emplace_back(100);
    v.emplace_back(200);
}
```

In theory, `reserve()` does not construct anything, as opposite to `resize()`. Also, `emplace_back()` is constructing "in place" objects, so none of this code is writing over an already constructed constant object.

Despite that, even writing the first line, `std::vector<const int> v;`, is already resulting in compilation error. Why is not allowed at all to have a `std::vector` of constants?

Comment: Some useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t

Comment: `emplace_back` has to handle case of resize, even if not called.

Comment: @Jarod42 `resize` doesn't technically need to have problems with `const` though unless the type is move-only.

Comment: Or rather, reallocation doesn't.

Comment: Yes add another specialized definition to the standard... _screams in `std::vector<bool>`_

Answer (score 1):

As the link provided by Bathsheba tells you, the problem is that `std::vector<T>` is really `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>`. Up to C++20, `std::allocator<T>::address()` had two overloads, one which takes `T&` and one which takes `T const&`. The problem with `T=const int` should be obvious. C++ has no such thing as extra-const, so both overloads are equally good.

Comment: The problem is not the return type but the argument it takes (reference vs const-reference which collapses if T is const). The return type of a function is not considered for the signature in overload resolution, so if the two `address()` overloads would only differ in the return type, we had a problem regardless whether `T` is constant or nor.

Comment: @n314159: Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

While the "why" is best read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t) there are some easy ways to get what you want:

```cpp
template<class T>
class as_const {
    T t;
public:
    as_const(T& t_): t(t_) {}
    as_const(const as_const&) = default;
    as_const(as_const &&) = delete;
    as_const& operator=(const as_const&) = default;
    as_const& operator=(as_const&&) = delete;

    operator const T&() const {
       return t;
    }
    const T& operator*() const { 
    // Or just a get method, anyway it's nicer to also have an explicit getter
       return t;
    }
};

std::vector<as_const<int>> vec;
vec.reserve(2)
vec.emplace_back(100);
vec.emplace_back(200);
```

You even can decide "how constant" your wrapper should be and provide the move constructors (note that `t` is not constant per-se in `as_const`) if you think that is reasonable for your use-case.

Note that you cannot prohibit the reallocation of your vector in this way. If you want to do that (and don't want to use a compile-time size array since you now your size only at runtime) take a look at [`std::unique_ptr<T[]>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). But note that in this case you first have to create a mutable variant and then reseat it in a const variant, since the underlying array gets default initialized and you cannot change anything after that.

Of course there is also the possibility of working with an allocator and disallowing a reallocation. But that has no stl-implementation. There are some implementations for this type of behavior out there (I myself gave it a try once but that is a bit of a mess) but I do not know if there is anything in boost.