# Replace boost::bind with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

I would like to replace a `boost::bind` with a lambda. Can you please advise on how to go about doing this?

I have a function declared as

```
bool myFunction(const vector<double>& input, vector<double>& output) const
{
    ...
}
...
...
boost::bind<bool>(std::mem_fn(&classname::myFunction), this, _1, _2) // Replace with lambda
```

Comment: Makes sense. `std::span` doesn't allocate to there you can have `const T`s. You probably need to write it without using `vector` if the aim is to mimic `span`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get an error trying to declare `vector<const double>`.

> The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator is ill-formed.'

Confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t)

So let's assume you can change the signature of myFunction to be:

```
bool myFunction(const vector<double>& input, vector<double>& output)
{
    return false;
}
```

To set:

```
auto fn = [this](const vector<double>& input, vector<double>& output) {
    return myFunction(input, output);
};
```

Or if you need to save fn off as a member variable:

```
std::function<bool(const vector<double>&, vector<double>&)> fn =
    [this](const vector<double>& input, vector<double>& output) {
        return myFunction(input, output);
    };
```

To invoke:

```
fn(inputVector, outputVector);
```

Comment: or just [&], since [&} will exactly only capture what you use (including this)

Comment: @PepijnKramer - Correct.

Comment: C++14 option: `[this](auto&& in, auto&& out){ return myFunction(in, out); };`

Comment: @TedLyngmo what's the difference between `(const auto& input, auto& output)` and your suggestion of `(auto&& in, auto&& out)`.  Is it that the universal reference captures the `const` part for free?  Or something else?

Comment: @selbie Yes, they are forwarding references, so perhaps `std::forward`ing would be more appropriate - but then the shortness of it gets lost :-)